# .NET 3.5 SP 1 and Web Platform Installer

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, .net, patch-management, dotnet-framework, web-platform-installer

I manage a `Windows Server 2008 R2` box which has a `.NET Framework` related security issue that showed up in a recent security scan. Below are the security scan results:

```
The following Microsoft .NET Framework version(s) do not have the latest service pack installed:

  Installed version: Microsoft .NET Framework v3.5 SP 0
  Should be: Microsoft .NET Framework v3.5 SP 1
```

I used the `Web Platform Installer` (`WPI`) to expedite the installation of `PHP`, `.NET`, `IIS`, etc... Back when the server was first provisioned. As a result, the `WPI` is used to install updates.  When viewing the `.NET 3.5 Framework` status in `WPI`, it also indicates `SP1` is installed. The box has `.NET 4.6`, `.NET 3.5.1`, and `.NET 2` installed.

Since the `WPI` indicates that `.NET 3.5 SP 1` is already installed, I am at a loss of how to rectify it. The Add Features shows `3.5.1` installed but no option for adding `SP1`.

The Windows Control Panel Add/Remove Programs only lists `.NET 4.6`. Should I just use the `Server Manager` - remove features to uninstall `.NET 3.5.1` and then reinstall it?

Comment: Uninstall all versions of `.Net` and install `4.7`(latest). That should fix the issue. `.Net` versions are all backward compatible. You could also manually install the `sp1` update on the server if you wanna keep all of the `.Net` versions installed.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Is there any advantage to uninstalling all versions and then installing v4.7 vs trying to resolve the 3.5 SP 1 issue? Since .NET versions are all backward compatible, there should be no concern for applications with dependencies on older versions of .NET, right?

Comment: `Pros: Less disk space usage, less of a security target and less applications to patch/manage`. `Cons: Can't think of any`. Always test your application before making any framework change. What might look good on paper might not work in the real world. The `WPI` application is only an installer. Use Microsoft Update to install updates to the installed applications.

Comment: Would you like me to write my comment as an answer so that we can close this question?

Comment: Yes, I would greatly appreciate that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Recommended Answer:

Uninstall all versions of `.Net` and install `4.7`(latest as of writing). That should fix the issue.

`.Net` versions are all backward compatible.

---

## Alternate answer:

You could also manually install the `SP1` update on the server if you wanna keep all of the `.Net` versions installed.

---

## Pros and Cons:

(*For main answer*)

- **Pros**: Less disk space usage, less of a security target and less applications to patch/manage.
- **Cons**: Can't think of any.

---

## Final thoughts:

Always test your application before making any framework change. What might look good on paper might not work in the real world.

- The WPI application is only an installer.
- Use Microsoft Update to install updates to the installed applications.